# Odoo workflow - How to hide/show workflow stage dynamically

Tags: odoo, workflow, odoo-9

I have a workflow stages ( Draft > Confirmed > Rejected > Done )

My goal are the following:

- Initially I want to display in my workflow status as the following `"Draft > Confirmed > Done"`
- When i click "Mark as Rejected",  the workflow status should hide the "Done" status bar and replace it by the "Rejected"
- When i click "Mark as Done",  the workflow status should hide the "Reject" status bar and replace it by the "Done"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

check the attribute statusbar_visible

example

```
    <field name="state" widget="statusbar" **statusbar_visible**="open,close" statusbar_colors='{"pending":"blue"}' readonly="1"/>
```